# Huggingface models: how to store a different version of a model

Tags: huggingface-transformers, git-lfs, huggingface

I have a model that I pushed to the remote using the following code:

```py
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel

checkpoint = "./checkpoints-15/checkpoint-60"
    
model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

repo = "vincentclaes/emoji-predictor"
model.push_to_hub(repo, use_temp_dir=True)
processor.push_to_hub(repo, use_temp_dir=True)
```

On the UI I see my model under a `main` branch:
[image]

What if I want to store multiple versions of a model?

- Can I create a separate git branch?
- Can I create a git tag?

How do I do this using the huggingface tools?
Thinking `transformers`, `huggingface_hub`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a specific version or revision of a model from a specific branch, you can use the revision parameter

here the detail:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.from_pretrained.revision

So if you have different branch e.g "v2.0" you can add revision parameter as "v2.0"

```
model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained("vincentclaes/emoji-predictor", revision="v2.0")
```